# Numerical radial derivative of function evaluated on Cartesian grid

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

I have a radially symmetric function evaluated on a 3D Cartesian grid. How can I numerically calculate the radial derivative of the function?

For a simple example (spherical Gaussian), calculate derivatives df/dx, df/dy and df/dz:

```
# Parameters
start = 0
end = 5
n = 20

# Variables
x = np.linspace(start, end, num=n)
y = np.linspace(start, end, num=n)
z = np.linspace(start, end, num=n)
dx = (end - start) / n
dy = (end - start) / n
dz = (end - start) / n
x_grid, y_grid, z_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
eval_xyz = np.exp(-(x_grid ** 2 + y_grid ** 2 + z_grid ** 2))

# Allocate
df_dx = np.zeros((n, n, n))
df_dy = np.zeros((n, n, n))
df_dz = np.zeros((n, n, n))

# Calculate Cartesian gradient numerically
for x in range(eval_xyz.shape[0] - 1):
    for y in range(eval_xyz.shape[1] - 1):
        for z in range(eval_xyz.shape[2] - 1):

            df_dx[x, y, z] = (eval_xyz[x + 1, y, z] - eval_xyz[x, y, z]) / dx
            df_dy[x, y, z] = (eval_xyz[x, y + 1, z] - eval_xyz[x, y, z]) / dy
            df_dz[x, y, z] = (eval_xyz[x, y, z + 1] - eval_xyz[x, y, z]) / dz
```

Is it then possible to easily calculate the radial derivative df/dr from the Cartesian derivatives?

Comment: thats rather a math question, but yes. derive the derivative `d_f/d_phi` and `d_f/d_r` with the corresponding formulas (wikipedia might help).

Comment: and df/dr = sqrt((df/dx)^2 + (df/dy)^2), so what do you need more? (as fas as i remember from calculus class...)

Comment: I suppose that the example function `exp(-(x**2+y**2+z**2))` is just an example? Because otherwise, shuffling numerical derivatives around is more work and possibly even slower. Also, it's better to use (f[y+1] - f[y-1])/(2*dy) for the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to express the radial derivatives as sum of Cartesian derivatives, taking into account theta and phi at each point which can be expressed in Cartesian coordiantes as: [image: Equation]

The code therefore becomes:

```
theta_val = theta(i * dx, j * dy, k * dz)
phi_val = phi(i * dx, j * dy)
            
df_dr[i, j, k] = df_dx[i, j, k] * np.sin(theta_val) * np.cos(phi_val) \
                 + df_dy[i, j, k] * np.sin(theta_val) * np.sin(phi_val) \
                 + df_dz[i, j, k] * np.cos(theta_val)
```

Where theta and phi are calculated carefully to deal with divide by zero

```
def theta(x, y, z):

    if x == 0 and y == 0 and z == 0:
        return 0

    elif z == 0:
        return np.pi / 2

    elif x == 0 and y == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        return np.arctan(np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2) / z)


def phi(x, y):

    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        return 0

    elif x == 0:
        return np.pi / 2

    elif y == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        return math.atan2(y, x)
```

Comment: It's probably good to clarify how to evaluate this expression in practie without getting divide errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. And for your earlier comment, yes this particular example is not worth differentiating numerically but as a minimal working example I thought it would be appropriate.

Comment: Arctan(y/x) doesn't distinguish correctly between positive and negative x and y. Also, it's more efficient to evaluate e.g. `sin(theta) = sqrt(x**2+y**2)/sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`; use np.where to deal with division by zero issues.

Comment: What would you suggest to then use as functions for sin(theta), cos(theta), cos(phi) and sin(phi)? I am not familiar with np.where

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer is a step in the right direction, but there are some issues both in the answer and in the code generating the Cartesian derivatives.

These lines have a problem:

```
x = np.linspace(start, end, num=n)
dx = (end - start) / n
```

The step size is actually `(end-start)/(n-1)`.

Here:

```
x_grid, y_grid, z_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
df_dx[x, y, z] = (eval_xyz[x + 1, y, z] - eval_xyz[x, y, z]) / dx
```

you fell in the trap of `meshgrid`'s default setting: `meshgrid(np.arange(n1), np.arange(n2))` will return arrays in the shape `(n2, n1)` unless you add the parameter `indexing='ij'`. Because you have size `n` in all dimensions, you will not get indexing errors to alert you, but you might be spending a lot of time trying to debug why the numbers make no sense.

When you manipulate multidimensional arrays, it's a good idea to set the sizes in different directions to slightly different values, so that you can easily check that the array shapes are what you want them to be.

Also, you should generally evaluate the derivative as `(f[i+1]-f[i-1])/(2*dx)`, which is correct up to the second order in x.

```
for x in range(eval_xyz.shape[0] - 1):
    for y in range(eval_xyz.shape[1] - 1):
        for z in range(eval_xyz.shape[2] - 1):
```

When working with numpy, you should always try to vectorize operations rather than writing out for loops that potentially need to iterate over thousands of elements.

Here is code that calculates the Cartesian derivative and then the radial derivative.

```
import numpy as np

def get_cartesian_gradient(f, xyzsteps):
    """For f shape (nx, ny, nz), return gradient as (3, nx, ny, nz) shape.
    
    xyzsteps is a (3,) array.
    
    Note: edge points of the gradient array are set to NaN.
    (Exercise for the reader to implement those).
    """
    
    fshape = f.shape
    grad = np.full((3,) + fshape, np.nan, dtype=np.float64)
    
    sl, sm, sr = slice(0, -2), slice(1, -1), slice(2, None)

    # Note: multiplying is faster than dividing.
    grad[0, sm, sm, sm] = (f[sr, sm, sm] - f[sl, sm, sm]) * (0.5/xyzsteps[0])
    grad[1, sm, sm, sm] = (f[sm, sr, sm] - f[sm, sl, sm]) * (0.5/xyzsteps[1])
    grad[2, sm, sm, sm] = (f[sm, sm, sr] - f[sm, sm, sl]) * (0.5/xyzsteps[2])
    
    return grad

def get_dfdr_from_cartesian(grad, x1s, y1s, z1s):
    """Return df/dr array from gradient(f).
    
    grad.shape must be (3, nx, ny, nz)
    return shape (nx, ny, nz).
    """
    _, nx, ny, nz = grad.shape
    
    # we need sin(theta), cos(theta), sin(phi), and cos(phi)
    
    # rxy: shape (nx, ny, 1)
    rxy = np.sqrt(x1s.reshape(-1, 1, 1)**2 + y1s.reshape(1, -1, 1)**2)
    # r: shape (nx, ny, nz)
    r = np.sqrt(rxy**2 + z1s.reshape(1, 1, -1)**2)
    
    # change zeros to NaN
    r = np.where(r==0, np.nan, r)
    rxy = np.where(rxy==0, np.nan, rxy)
    
    cos_theta = z1s.reshape(1, 1, -1) / r
    sin_theta = rxy / r
    cos_phi = x1s.reshape(-1, 1, 1) / rxy
    sin_phi = y1s.reshape(1, -1, 1) / rxy
    
    # and the derivative
    dfdr = (grad[0]*cos_phi + grad[1]*sin_phi)*sin_theta + grad[2]*cos_theta
    return dfdr

x1s = np.linspace(-1, 1, 19)
y1s = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
z1s = np.linspace(-1, 1, 23)

xs, ys, zs = np.meshgrid(x1s, y1s, z1s, indexing='ij')
xyzsteps = [x1s[1]-x1s[0], y1s[1]-y1s[0], z1s[1]-z1s[0]]

def func(x, y, z):
    return x**2 + y**2 + z**2
    
def dfdr_analytical(x, y, z):
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    return 2*r
    

# grad has shape (3, nx, ny, nz)
grad = get_cartesian_gradient(func(xs, ys, zs), xyzsteps)

dfdr = get_dfdr_from_cartesian(grad, x1s, y1s, z1s)

# test
diff = dfdr - dfdr_analytical(xs, ys, zs)
assert np.nanmax(np.abs(diff)) < 1e-14
```

Note that I've chosen to return NaN values for points on the z-axis, because df/dr is not defined there unless f(x,y,z) is rotationally symmetric around the z-axis and has df/dr=0 in all directions. This is something that is not guaranteed for an arbitrary dataset.

The reason for replacing zeros in the denominators by `np.nan` using `np.where` is because dividing by zero will give warning messages, whereas dividing by nan won't.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realised that about np.multigrid, good to know. Unfortunately when I run your code I get grad and dfdr as arrays of NaN, without any actual values?

Comment: Try `grad[1,1,:]` rather than `grad[0,0,:]`; see the note in the code: "Note: edge points of the gradient array are set to NaN.  (Exercise for the reader to implement those)."